# How do I maintain the position of internal elements when toggling the width of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#presets-toggle").click(function () {

      if ($(this).text() === "►"){
        $(this).text("◄")
      }
      else {
        $(this).text("►");
      }

      $("#presets").animate({width:'toggle'},250);

  });
});
```

The diminishing width alters the layout while toggling.  I would like them to appear fixed.

Comment: You will have to show the relevant HTML and CSS.  Can't answer layout questions without seeing the layout.

Comment: a jsfiddle is required...

Comment: which one to set fixed #presets-toggle or #presets ?

Comment: #presets is the containing element.

I'll put together a jsfiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general solution, assuming that your HTML is something like:

```
<div id="presets"></div>
<div id="presets-toggle">►</div>
<div id="noise"></div>
```

To begin, add a 'container' `div` to your 'presets' `div`:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="presets"></div>
</div>
```

Then, depending on your situation, you'll have two options to proceed with:

> a) add the following CSS, changing its values to those of your 'presets'
>   `div`:

```
#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

> b) OR, if the `div`'s dimensions are unknown:

```
var height = $("#presets").height() + "px";
var width = $("#presets").width() + "px";
$("#presets-toggle").click(function () {
    if ($(this).text() === "►") {
        $(this).text("◄")
    } else {
        $(this).text("►");
    }
    $("#container").css({
        'height': height,
        'width': width
    });
    $("#presets").animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, 250);
});
```